# Pass a slice of custom type from Go to C#

Tags: c#, .net, go, cgo

I am trying to integrate a Go application inside a large C# project.
By using CGO it is easy to export functions from Go to C#, especially when the Go function return a generic type.

However, I have the need to call a Go function which return a slice of custom type from C#, possibly casting the slice to a C# list or array.

The Go function look like this

```
func Myfunc(n []int, m float64) []Res{...}
```

where type Res is

```
type Res struct {
    w IW
    p []Prs
    ti int64
    ms   int64
}

type Prs struct {
    mmz float64
    cge    int
    itntn int64
}

type IW struct {
    ledg float64
    redg float64
}
```

I could not find any documentation or example on the web, can I do this somehow?

Comment: «slice of custom type from C#»—which of the types from your example is this? `Res`, `Prs` or `IW`?

Comment: I need to pass `Res`, in which both `Prs` and `IW` are nested into

Comment: Hey, this is sort of obvious, you know ;-) The question was: which of these types _is from C#?_

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. In C# I have an array, which I cast to a go slice (`n []int`) and a double (`m float64`), i.e. the input of `Myfunc`. The output of this is `Res` that I have to cast to a list or array so that I can keep working with it in the rest of the C# project.

Comment: Ah, I see: a language issue: you meant the bit "from C#" to be related to "to call" rather than the word "type", OK. So have you not found anything useful in the results of a search query like [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+P%2FInvoke+golang)?

Comment: I see. Honestly I have no idea what to look for :) I roughly know Go, but just stated playing with C#, so not sure in which of the two worlds I should look for inspirations to solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how C# invoke Go, let's assume we are going to invoke Go function from C code.

1. You need define `Res struct` in C file. like cgo_interface.h
2. Then you write a cgo file like this:

```
package cinvokego

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I ${include}
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L ${libs}
#include "cgo_interface.h"
*/
import "C"

func GoFuncs(retArr *unsafe.Pointer, otherargs int) {
    // allocate memory and fill the retArr in here
}
```

3. Then use `go build --buildmode=c-archive  cinvokego.go`
4. Then you will get header file and archive file generated by go build.
5. Then you use header and archive like normal C resource.
6. Then use C# to invoke C resource.